# Alternative for dataset/datatable returned from ajax enabled wcf service?

Tags: wcf, dataset

I have seen blogs and people saying `Returning dataset/datatable from an ajax enabled wcf service` is a bad idea.... I have gone through this [Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,d88f7539-10d8-4697-8c6e-1badb08bb3f5.aspx)  about datasets fr0m wcf...

So what is the alternative for dataset returned form ajax enabled wcf service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically, on your server side (where your service method is implemented), either use straight ADO.NET SqlDataReader and assemble the data retrieved into custom classes, or use an ORM like Linq-to-SQL or the Entity Framework or NHibernate or ... or... or..... to do this job.

Then, when you need to return data, either return a `List<MyClass>` or some other structure, which gets serialized into JSON or XML and doesn't carry the overhead of a whole DataSet/DataTAble.